# String array to integer

Tags: java

I have a text file with the name of "w1_slave" as follows:

```
3c 00 4b 46 ff ff 0d 10 16 : crc=16 YES

3c 00 4b 46 ff ff 0d 10 16 t=29937
```

From the above, I only need to extract the integer number 29937, and my code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // create token1
    String token1 = "";

    // create Scanner inFile1
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    // detect delimiter "," and " "
    Scanner w1Slave = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Hamid/Desktop/w1_slave.txt")).useDelimiter(",| ");

    List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

    // while loop
    while (w1Slave.hasNext()) {
      // find next line
      token1 = w1Slave.next();
      temps.add(token1);
    }
    w1Slave.close();

    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
    int tempsArrayLength = tempsArray.length - 1;
    System.out.println(tempsArray[tempsArrayLength]);
```

The output is **t=29937**. Could you tell me how I can extract just **29937** as an integer or double number, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parseInt or parseDouble functions:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[tempsArrayLength]);
```

or

```
double number = Double.parseDouble(tempsArray[tempsArrayLength]);
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to add `=` as a delimiter - replace

```
.useDelimiter(",| ");
```

with

```
.useDelimiter(",|= ");
```

To convert it to a `double`, use

```
double value = 0;
try {
    value = Double.parseDouble(temps.get(temps.size() - 1));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // not a number - do something
}
```

You don't need to convert the list to an array - you can delete this part of your code:

```
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
int tempsArrayLength = tempsArray.length - 1;
System.out.println(tempsArray[tempsArrayLength]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The delimiter works, but the conversion does not work. it returns  0  instead of  29937.

Comment: That's because your conversion from `List` to array is not correct, and unnecessary. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but with double not with integer. so I change the codes.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use the substring function.

```
String strNumber = tempsArray[tempsArrayLength].substring(2);
```

Then use parseInt to get the integer value.

```
int nNumber = Integer.parseInt(strNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

You was very near to your code. i think you need to modify your code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create token1
        String token1 = "";

        // create Scanner inFile1
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        // detect delimiter "," and " "
        Scanner w1Slave = new Scanner(new File(C:/Users/Hamid/Desktop/w1_slave.txt")).useDelimiter(",| ");

        List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

        // while loop
        while (w1Slave.hasNext()) {
          // find next line
          token1 = w1Slave.next();
          temps.add(token1);
        }
        w1Slave.close();

        String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
        int tempsArrayLength = tempsArray.length - 1;
        String str[]=tempsArray[tempsArrayLength].split("=");
        // System.out.println(tempsArray[tempsArrayLength]);
        int i=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        System.out.println(i);

}
```